# Including Google Maps to my module is throwing error

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am trying to add google-maps to my module, but I am getting this issue - Error: [$injector:unpr] and something like this at the end -

```
angular.module("app", ["google-maps"])
angular.module("app.controllers", ["ngCookies"]).controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$cookies",
    function($scope, $location, $cookies) {
        return $scope.isSpecificPage = function() {
        }, $scope.main = {
           }
        }
    }]).controller("DashboardCtrl", ["$scope", "$cookies", "$location", "google-maps",  
        function($scope, $cookies, $location) {
            return $scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
    },
    zoom: 8
};
    }])
```

I followed this like placing the files in the same order- https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use but I am facing issues. Could someone please respond to this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `google-maps` dependancy is not included properly in controller `DashboardCtrl`

```
controller("DashboardCtrl", ["$scope", "$cookies", "$location", "google-maps",  
        function($scope, $cookies, $location) {
```

Can you please remove the dependancy

```
controller("DashboardCtrl", ["$scope", "$cookies", "$location",  
        function($scope, $cookies, $location) {
```

Comment: This is correct, google-maps should be a module dependency, not a an injected service.

Comment: I am facing issues if I remove the google-maps from dashboardCtrl. 

Here is what I got - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  when I use


angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "google-maps", "app.controllers", "app.directives", "app.form.validation"], function($httpProvider) {});